# Join 2 identical pandas dataframe into multi level row key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have 2 dataframe with identical index and column. I need to join or concatenate them into one dataframe. The code to generate the data is as such:

```
import pandas as pd
sites = pd.Index(['AAA', 'BBB','CCC', 'DDD'], name='SITELIST')
vvv = pd.DataFrame({'KK':[1,2,3,4],'GG':[2,3,4,5], 'RR':[6,5,4,3]}, index = sites)
ttt = pd.DataFrame({'KK':[11,22,33,34],'GG':[23,33,34,35], 'RR':[26,25,24,23]}, index = sites)
```

The resulting dataframe is

```
print(vvv)

          KK  GG  RR
SITELIST            
AAA        1   2   6
BBB        2   3   5
CCC        3   4   4
DDD        4   5   3
```

```
print(ttt)

          KK  GG  RR
SITELIST            
AAA       11  23  26
BBB       22  33  25
CCC       33  34  24
DDD       34  35  23
```

When I use concat to join those two dataframes with the following code:

```
res2 = pd.concat([vvv, ttt], axis=0, keys=["VVV", "TTT"], names=['Sensor', 'Site'])
```

I get this as a result:

```
print(res2)

             KK  GG  RR
Sensor Site            
VVV    AAA    1   2   6
       BBB    2   3   5
       CCC    3   4   4
       DDD    4   5   3
TTT    AAA   11  23  26
       BBB   22  33  25
       CCC   33  34  24
       DDD   34  35  23
```

I need to join them so to get the result such as:

```
              KK  GG  RR
Site  Sensor
AAA   VVV      1   2   6
      TTT     11  23  26
BBB   VVV      2   3   5
      TTT     22  33  25
CCC   VVV      3   4   4
      TTT     33  34  24
DDD   VVV      4   5   3
      TTT     34  35  23
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your issue seems to be with the order of the rows: you can simply sort by "Site" column like so: `df.sort_values('Site')`

Comment: Add `.reorder_levels([1, 0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print(res2.swaplevel().sort_index(level=0).reindex(['VVV','TTT'],level=1))
```

---

```
             KK  GG  RR
Site Sensor            
AAA  VVV      1   2   6
     TTT     11  23  26
BBB  VVV      2   3   5
     TTT     22  33  25
CCC  VVV      3   4   4
     TTT     33  34  24
DDD  VVV      4   5   3
     TTT     34  35  23
```

Comment: From @Rocco, I also got
`print(res2.sort_values('Site').reset_index(level=['Site','Sensor']).set_index(['Site', 'Sensor']))` which somewhat got the same result.